# Building wheel for pyscard (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python-3.x, read-the-docs

I have pyscard within requirements.txt. Therefore the build on readthedocs is failing:

```
Running setup.py install for pyscard: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyscard did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'smartcard.scard._scard' extension
      swigging smartcard/scard/scard.i to smartcard/scard/scard_wrap.c
      swig -python -outdir smartcard/scard -DPCSCLITE -o smartcard/scard/scard_wrap.c smartcard/scard/scard.i
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/smartcard
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/smartcard/scard
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DVER_PRODUCTVERSION=2,0,2,0000 -DVER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR=2.0.2 -DPCSCLITE=1 -Ismartcard/scard/ -I/usr/include/PCSC -I/usr/local/include/PCSC -I/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/include/python3.7m -c smartcard/scard/helpers.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/smartcard/scard/helpers.o
      smartcard/scard/helpers.c:28:10: fatal error: winscard.h: No such file or directory
       #include <winscard.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyscard

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have tried to skip pyscard in docs/conf.py:

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['pyscard']
```

and in setup.py:

```
if os.getenv('READTHEDOCS'):
        requirements = [x for x in requirements if "pyscard" not in x]
```

but I still get the same error.
Have you encountered something similar? If so, how have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added into .readthedocs.yml:

```
build:
  apt_packages:
    - swig
    - pcscd
    - libpcsclite-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

> This header file is provided by pcsc-lite. Install libpcsclite-dev (or similar) package.

https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pyscard/issues/78

Edit: please follow [Manuel Kaufmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821421/13240100) for detailed solution

Comment: But how can I install it? Guess, I can not put it into requirements.. How to tell RTD to get this package?

Comment: you can put it in requirements.txt

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpcsclite-dev (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libpcsclite-dev

Comment: Aah I did not see that its not a pip package. You should go with @Manuel Kaufmann 's answer. Seems better approach.

Comment: In my answer, there is a link to the FAQ that explains how to use `build.apt_packages` to install system dependencies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If `pyscard` **is not required to build your documentation**, you should remove it from your documentation `requirements.txt`. This is the most common case.

You may need to split your current `requirements.txt`:

- `requirements.txt` with all the dependencies
- `docs/requirements.txt` with only the dependencies to build the documentation (*without* `pyscard`)

Then, in your `readthedocs.yaml` file (see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html), you can use:

```
python:
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

On the other hand, **if `pyscard` is required to build your documentation**, you can take a look at the FAQ from the documentation https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules

Comment: I have requirements split as you mentioned. The pyscard is in main requirements.